# Can an Intellect Devourer use racial abilities while piloting a body?

Tags: adnd-2e, possession

My specific situation is that an intellect devourer is hiding inside a crystal dragon, hoping to wait until the other gem dragons enter their first dragon sleep in order to use them to help grow its larvae into adult intellect devourers.  I realized after I'd had the "crystal dragon" use its breath weapon that I wasn't sure if it should be able to.  2e citations are best, but I'll accept other editions including Pathfinder if 2e can't be found (I haven't found anything yet, or I wouldn't be asking).  The MM entry just says it "animates the body from within".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The 2e Complete Pscionics Handbook has a set of monster manual entries for pscionic monsters in the back, including an expanded entry on both the intellect devourer and its larvae.

The entry explains that after the devourer enters the body, it either eats the brain or takes control (in contrast to the Monster Manual which states it eats the brain then takes control). If the devourer takes control, it uses a special form of Domination that can be used on intact dead minds.

Per Domination: "The victim's abilities are neither diminished nor enhanced by this power. The subject can be forced to use any power or ability he normally can-assuming the psionicist knows about it."

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to check the CPH version of the Intellect Devourer.  You're completely right, and I strongly doubt I'm going to get a better answer than this, so I'm hitting that checkmark now so I don't forget to do it later.